# The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) CharSequence, int

Tags: java, android, string, cast

Estou tentando fazer a concatenação de um texto em `CharSequence` com `int`, mas o java alerta que não é possível fazer essa conversão dizendo:

> The operator + is undefined for the argument type(s) CharSequence, int

Eu já tentei retirar o *casting* de `CharSequence`, além de "dar" um `.toString()` em tudo, mas o aplicativo não inicia quando eu faço isso.

```
package br.edu.ifgoiano.cadastrodeprodutos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Cadastrar extends Activity {
    Principal principal = new Principal();
/*  private int cont = 0;
    private int varAux;*/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastrar);
    }

    public void tirarFoto(View view) {
        Intent tiraFoto = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        startActivityForResult(tiraFoto, 0);
    }
    **public void qntProd() {
        int cont = 0;
        if (cont == 0) {
            principal.quanti.setText((CharSequence) "Você não possui produtos cadastrados.");
        } else {
            principal.quanti.setText("Você possui " + cont +" produtos cadastrados.");
        }**
    }
    /*public int qntProdCadastrados() {
            if(cont == 0) {
                varAux =  cont;
            }else if(cont > 0){
                varAux = cont;
            }
        cont++;
        return varAux;
    }*/
    public void enviar(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "O cadastro foi realizado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        Intent telaInicial = new Intent(this, Principal.class);
        startActivity(telaInicial);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(data != null) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            if(bundle != null) {
                Bitmap img = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                ImageView imagem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagem);
                imagem.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: O que é `quanti`? Por que está usando `(CharSequence)`?

Comment: Perdão... `quanti` é o TextView que vai escrever na tela. Estou usando CharSequence por que o `TextView` utiliza uma sequência de caracteres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que só isto é para funcionar dado que a `String` ser subtipo de `CharSequence`:

```
principal.quanti.setText("Você possui " + cont + " produtos cadastrados.")
```

Se precisar mesmo, pode fazer:

```
principal.quanti.setText((CharSequence)("Você possui " + cont + " produtos cadastrados."))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/CharSequence.java).

Comment: Eu já tentei fazer os dois casos, no entanto o app não roda, dando o erro `Unfurtunalety, CadastroDeProdutos has stopped`. Você prefere que eu coloque o código inteiro ?

Comment: Mas pode ter parado por muitas razões. Se você tirar isto ele funciona normal? Na verdade esse erro deveria ser pego na compilação, então uma coisa não tem nada a ver com outra.

Comment: Sem isso ele funciona corretamente.

Comment: mas esse código sequer está executando, ele entra no `if`, não faz sentido.

Comment: Esse código é para dizer a quantidade de produtos "cadastrados" no sistema. Irei colocar o código completo.